# What makes Breadth First Search algorithm slower than Depth First Search(both are shown below)?

Tags: depth-first-search, breadth-first-search, maze

I am using DFS and BFS to solve mouse in a maze problem where the mouse is allowed to move either towards right or upwards. Since the branching factor is just two with the maze being a 5x5 matrix i expected BFS to be way quicker than DFS but turns out to be the other way around. 
DFS takes 6793300 nano seconds
BFS takes 26359600 nano seconds

What could possibly explains this difference? Does additional data structure used in BFS cause such overhead?

**DFS:**

```
 int performMazeSearchDFS(int i, int j, int[][] maze, int destI, int destJ, int size, int moveCount) 
 {
    int result = moveCount;
    if (i == destI && j == destJ) {
      return moveCount;
    }

    if(j+1 < size && maze[i][j+1] != 1) {
        result = performMazeSearchDFS(i, j + 1, maze, destI, destJ, size, moveCount+1);
     if(result > moveCount) {
            return result;
        }
    }

    if (i-1 >= 0 && maze[i-1][j] != 1) { // no improvement from previous moves
        result = performMazeSearchDFS(i - 1, j, maze, destI, destJ, size, moveCount+1);
        if(result > moveCount) {
            return result;
         }
    }
   moveCount = moveCount -1;
   return moveCount;
}
```

**BFS:**

```
 private class Coordinates{
    private int i;
    private int j;
    public Coordinates(int iCord, int jCord){
        i= iCord;
        j=jCord;
    }
    public int getI(){return i;}
    public int getJ(){return j;}
    public boolean equals(Object toCompare){
        if(toCompare instanceof  Coordinates ){
            Coordinates coOrdX  = (Coordinates)toCompare;
            if(this.i == coOrdX.getI() && this.j == coOrdX.getJ()){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

private class History{
    private Coordinates parent;
    private Coordinates current;
    public History(Coordinates par, Coordinates curr){
        parent = par;
        current = curr;
    }
    public Coordinates getParent(){return parent;}
    public Coordinates getCurrent(){return current;}
}

public boolean performMazeSearchBFS(int i, int j, int[][] maze, int destI, int destJ, int size) {
    LinkedList<History>  nodeQ = new LinkedList<>();
    HashMap<Coordinates,Boolean> visitedNode = new HashMap<>();
    boolean found = false;
    nodeQ.add(new History(new Coordinates(-1,-1),(new Coordinates(i,j))));
    while(!nodeQ.isEmpty()) {
      History currNode = nodeQ.poll();
      visitedNode.put(new Coordinates(currNode.getCurrent().getI(), 
      currNode.getCurrent().getJ()),true);
      int m = currNode.current.getI();
      int n = currNode.current.getJ();
      if(currNode.current.getI() == destI && currNode.current.getJ() == destJ) {
        found = true;
        break;
      }
      if (m - 1 >= 0 && maze[m - 1][n] == 0 
          && !visitedNode.containsKey(new Coordinates(m - 1, n))) {
      if (m - 1 >= 0 && maze[m - 1][n] == 0 ) {
          nodeQ.add(new History(new Coordinates(m, n), new Coordinates(m - 1, n)));
      }
      if (n + 1 < size && maze[m][n] == 0 
         && !visitedNode.containsKey(new Coordinates(m, n + 1))) {
         nodeQ.add(new History(new Coordinates(m, n), new Coordinates(m, n + 1)));
      }
 }
      return found;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The speed really depends on what your are searching for and the stricture of the graph.
If you search all paths in a graph, the speed should be similar.
If you search for nodes close to the root, or you need the shortest path, BFS is likely to be faster. 
DFS might be faster if you search node that are deep in the graph, far from the root, and you do not need the shortest path.